# Как выбрать минимальное значение из базы SQL

Tags: sql

Необходимо получить имя и продолжительность самой короткой песни, без вложенных запросов. Записываю так (MS SQL):

```
SELECT name, duration FROM songs
GROUP BY name, duration
HAVING duration=MIN(duration);
```

Почему-то выводит все песни, а не одну - с минимальной продолжительностью.

Подскажите почему и что я неверное понимаю?

Comment: `GROUP BY` и `HAVING` нужны для агрегирования многих записей. А нужна, насколько я понял, всего одна.

Comment: В тексте вопроса хорошо бы писать о каком диалекте SQL идет речь. Или какой СУБД идет запрос? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: MS SQL, поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет об **одной** записи *(одна самая короткая песня)*, то запрос вот такой:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, duration
FROM songs
ORDER BY duration
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите `GROUP BY name, duration`

[Демо на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe884/1)

Comment: Не могу, т.к. без группировки HAVING не работает

Comment: он будет работать,  проверьте. а я ща выложу пример

Comment: @Konstantin смотрите пример в ответе

Comment: На фидле работает, а вот в мой MS SQL ошибка: "Столбец "songs.duration" недопустим в предложении HAVING, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY." Видимо особенность реализации стандарта.

Comment: @splash58 хе-хе, не валидируется SQL-запрос, потому что у клиента скорее всего не MySQL ;-)

Comment: :) логично, про это я не подумал

Comment: @splash58 а вообще твоё решение отличное. Мой +1. Сегодня я открыл для себя SQLFiddle и базовый синтаксис MySQL :)

Comment: @ InterfaceUnknown значит, не зря писал :)